# Why does microsoft use c, c++ instead of c# to develop windows?

Tags: programming-languages

I have found that windows is written in [c, c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/580300/894563). C# is likely to make you more productive than C/C++. What are reasons to develop windows in c,c++???

Comment: An interesting question, but this is not the place for it.

Comment: Side note, look into COSMOS. Windows will probably never be developed with it, but you can make your own OS in .Net languages.

Comment: C# Requires a managed layer. Thus you cannot use C# directly on the CPU. That's why.

Comment: Although most people find it very low level, an operating system has usually not much to do with user interface, or file explorers, etc. It basically has to do with management of the machine such that several programs can work on it efficiently and toegether. C# makes abstraction of this, so would be close to impossible to write it that way. C/C++ can manage memory of a program, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird question, how are we supposed to know Microsofts motives for using c/c++? My only guess is that c++ appeared some 17 years before c#, and normal c appeared even earlier, thus they started out using c/c++ and just didnt bother switching languages..

Comment: It has nothing to do with timing. There is a principal difference between C/C++ and C#. C# is a managed language, requiring a mediation layer, just like Java. Windows is in operating system and as such requires access to resources that aren't accessible by managed language directly.