# Which language has been used to code Windows OS?

Tags: linux, windows, unix

I want to know which **programming language** has been used to **code Windows OS**. And is there a specific language programmers choose to make operating systems ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580292/what-languages-are-windows-mac-os-x-and-linux-written-in

Answer (score 0):

As far as kernels go:

The windows kernel is written in C.

C is the only real choice in my opinion. C++ is too bloated and the exception model may be hard to work with. Assembly doesn't provide enough abstraction, and most everything else needs a VM.

Answer (score 0):

- Windows: C dialects.
- Is there a specific language programmers choose to make operating systems?

  Yes. In general, [low-level programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language) are preferred. You need to be "close to the hardware". But, after this base for an OS is layed, then higher-level languages, which provide more abstraction allow a faster development.

  http://wiki.osdev.org/Languages
- If you want to get into "hobby" OS development a good starting point is:
  http://wiki.osdev.org/

Answer (score 0):

According to some people at Microsoft, it is a mixture of C, C++ and C# (see [MSDN forum](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65a1fe05-9c1d-48bf-bd40-148e6b3da9f1/what-programming-language-is-windows-written-in?forum=windowshpcacademic))